# Eclipse Gynamide and JDK compatibility

Tags: eclipse, ganymede, jdk1.4

i am using **JDK1.4.2_02** on my system, which is required to run my ATG Dynamo server. I have tried to run Eclipse 'Ganymede'-( 3.4/3.4.2). But facing problem, its asking to use JDK1.5, which I cant use. Since ATG Dynamodosent run on JDK1.5 .

I googled and found that Eclipse 3.2 / Callisto is compatible with JDK 1.4.2, but its not available in our software list. The only older version availabe is  Eclipse 'Ganymede'-( 3.4/3.4.2).

**Is there any way to use Eclipse 'Ganymede'-( 3.4/3.4.2) with JDK 1.4.2_02.**

Regards
Mayank

Answer (score 1):

If it is not compatible then you won't be able to run it with Java 4.

But why don't you install two JVM versions on your server? You could have Java 4 to run your ATG Dynamo server and a more recent JVM to run Eclipse.

Moreover why can't you run your ATG dynamo server with a more recent JVM? AFAIK JVMs are backward compatible.

Comment: I am not installing recent version of JVM , because I need to run application using Eclipse and my application is deployed on ATG Dynamo server that run on JAVA4 only. Still I am looking for solution,one solution I have already got to use RSA (IBM Rational Software Architect), But problem with RSA is that its very slow.

Comment: @MayankTiwari Within the Eclipse launch configuration you can choose which JVM to run your application on. So it is still possible to use Eclipse with a recent JVM and run any other application (even debugging within Eclipse) on another JVM.